# !important inline styles in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's there a way to add inline styles with the !important override?

```
style={
  height: 20+'!important'
};

<div style={style}></div>
```

This isn't working as I would have hoped.

Comment: Yeah trying to get some good transitional animations of lists. Need to know the exact height to get the smoothest animation.

Comment: watch out, I found out that setting a 'inline' style with react (as an object) with `!important` like you did there, will give problems if you update the property with another `!important` var. It will keep the first `!important` property and not update...

Comment: use actual CSS? I am still struggling that we are fighting what comes natural just to do it the react way...yet I'm still interested in that useRef answer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`20+'!important'` is `'20!important'`.

When you just give a number, react adds "px" for you; but you're using a string, so you have to specify the unit.  Also I'm pretty sure there needs to be a space between "!important" and whatever's to the left of it.

```
style={{ height: '20px !important' }};
```

Comment: Or just `'20px !important'`, since there is no need for string concatenation.

Comment: Worked in react 0.14.x but not in react 15.0.0

Comment: Same problem here `width:'100vw !important'` not working, but `width:100+'vw !important'` not even showing on the inspector.

Comment: I'm trying this with '%' and no luck. Without the `!important` flag at least I see my value with strike-through in the console.

Comment: There is an official statement on GitHub that they don't support `!important` on purpose. **So this answer cannot work!** However I don't share the opinion that you should never use `!important`, which is the reason they give to not support it in `React inline styles`. But there is another [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57293159/8412038).

Comment: @anarchist912 Just got the same gotchas this morning!!  Do you have the link to the official statement on their GitHub?

Comment: this probably should be updated with info regarding react 15 and later not supporting it

Comment: This won’t work with current version of React

Comment: "Official" (as in a React developer using 'we' in a GitHub comment) [statement](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881#issuecomment-127769813) is "it would be expensive to check every value for !important, so supporting this isn't awesome. Even if we do get a good option, it's unlikely we'd do this while we support IE8 because I don't want to go down that cssText path. This isn't really at all about dogma, I would say that _it's more about perf_." They know it can be done already with `ref` and no one has submitted a good RFC to support it yet so it's still not available.

Answer (score 51):

Apparently React does not support this. But i got this hack as i did my research

```
    <div ref={(node) => {
      if (node) {
        node.style.setProperty("float", "right", "important");
      }
    }}>                    
    </div>
```

Good luck:)

Official source: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881#issuecomment-542656865

Comment: wtf with react, makes all easy task harder

Comment: For anyone struggling with e.g. `fontWeight`, here property name should be in standard (non-react, non-camel-case) form, so use `font-weight` instead

Comment: Surprising in 2023, that React still doesn't support this in 2023!  Great hack, as it's simple and works like a charm!

Comment: It does not apply the property on the server side, though.

Answer (score 9):

A good trick to use which is cleaner and more consistent for other CSS properties:

```
ref={(el) => el && el.style.setProperty(<property>, <value>, "important")}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello You should take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to use Markdown to format your code on SO

Answer (score 7):

This is the only way I could get it to work with React 16.

```
const id="unique_id"; 
<React.Fragment>
    <style>
      {`
#${id} {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
      `}
    </style>
    <Frame id={id} />
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/), if you have a good reason to make use of `!important`, as the style props do not support `!important` and probably [won't](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881) in the future.

Here is an example where we overwrite Semantic-UI's `padding` on `grid columns`. You can actually leave out the `!important` as "[bumping up the specifity](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity)" is sufficient.

```
const StyledColumn = styled.div(({size}) => ({className: `${size} wide column`})`
    &&&&& {
        padding-top: 0.3rem !important;
        padding-bottom: 0.3rem !important;
    }
`
<StyledColumn size="three"></StyledColumn>
```

[&&&&&&](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity) <- bumps up specifity.

Answer (score 3):

This is originally answered by Daniel above. I just want to share my answer as I refactor his answer to work with hooks.

1. Define ref `const ref = useRef(null);`
2. Add ref to your desired node (ex. div, table) `<div ref={ref}></div>`
3. Add this code `ref.current.style.setProperty(<property>, <value>, "important")` inside useLayoutEffect

Please see the sample codes below

```
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";


const SampleComponent = () => {

   const ref = useRef(null);

   useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current.style.setProperty("border-top", "0px", "important");
  }, []);

   return (
      <div ref={ref}>
         {/* additional codes here */}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Note:

- property is in CSS format (ex. "border-top" )

Comment: For typescript: `const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah the way I found to do this was that already mentioned above:

```
const styles = (theme: any) => ({
    panelSize: {
        height: 480,
        width: 360,
    },
    progress: {
        height: '120px !important', 
        margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
        width: '120px !important'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

a slite improvment with modern syntax to make code shorter:

```
<div ref={(node) => 
        node?.style.setProperty("float", "right", "important")
    }>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with setting className prop

```
.height {
    height: 20px !important;
}

className={ styles.height }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the suggestions above for width, but could not get it to work.

This is what work for me, I created style.css file, and added in my case, width: 100% !important to a class, and then just import this file into my component, and call this class, and it work.

Comment: upvoted because although its not 'react' it works and i used the same method. There is also an npm module called WithImportant - which was made specifically for this but its more expensive than simple css in my opinion

Answer (score -4):

I was able to resolve it by doing something like this:

```
style={
  height: `20px ${" !important"}`
};

<div style={style}></div>
```

I had to add the space before "!important" because the browser kept removing that space when running the program.