# react jsx inline style not rendering when populated from a variable

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I added an inline style element to a div tag in a react component along with a className element. The className property renders but the style is not displaying.  I am setting from an object variable.  However, if I set the style element directly using double curly braces it works, just not working from a variable.

Here is an image of the object value I am using to set the style element.

[image]

This shows where the style element should be getting set as the component is rendering, the styleElement object has a value set at this point

[image]

This shows the component post rendering and the style element is not present

[image]

What would prevent the style element from rendering even though is it populated from an object containing CSS properties?

Comment: please share your codes of component and where you using it.

Comment: The background style syntax is correct, and it's not the problem as mentioned in the answers. We can not help if you do not share your code.

Comment: @MohamedEl-Refaie I think you're wrong. The problem is that React doesn't support using `!important`: [Here's the source for that](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881). The OP's background style syntax may be correct using plain HTML, but not when it comes to `React` and using the `style` property from `React`'s components.

Comment: @Kapobajza Yes, you are right. After doing some research, I found the adding !important will result in background suppression from the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `!important` is the main culprit here. Simply remove it and everything should render with the variable inside.

Inline CSS will, as a general rule, override any CSS in your stylesheet assuming the same level of specificity.

[Have a look at MDN for more info about specificity and `!important` to learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception)

Answer (score 5):

It seems like your issue lies in the `!important` part. React [doesn't support](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881) using `!important` in the style object. If you can get rid of that `!important` part it would be for the best, but if you can't then here is a workaround (taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669262/5049799)):

```
<div
  ref={(node) => {
    if (node) {
      node.style.setProperty('background', `url(${imageUrl}) no-repeat 50% 40%`, 'important');
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> use ES6 for this.

```
background: `url(${imageUrl}) no-repeat`
```

Comment: That did not work.  Getting the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

the background image syntax is

```
background-image: url("img_tree.gif");
```

You are missing the `"` on between the file name. change to

```
{ background: 'url("' + imageUrl + '") no-repeat 50% 40% !important' }
```

the other thing you might want to check is make sure `img_tree.gif` is actually the correct path, usually, it should relative path or absolute path, something like `./img_tree.gif` or `http://example.com/img_tree.gif`

also make sure have a background size

```
background-size: cover
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `"` surrounding the `imageURL`

```
{ background: "url(\"" + imageUrl + "\") no-repeat ..."}
```