# Apply !important to SVG fill property

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

im trying to apply `!important` to the fill property of a SVG file but it seems that the syntax here is wrong, the `!important` is not applied to the fill property and the `circle` element is rendered with black color.

I'm wondering how to apply `!important` to the fill property of SVG in react

```
<circle className="cls-1" cx="84.194" cy="83.49" r="83.48" style={{fill:'url(\'#linear-gradient\') !important', strokeWidth:'0px'}} />
```

Comment: `!important`  should apply to the rule, not to the content of the `url()` function, move it after the `)`.

Comment: @Kaiido sorry I mistyped, I have edit the question, the `!important` is apply to the `url()` rule but seems not working

Comment: For recent versions of React, you need a trick for it to "!important" to work with inline styles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074748/important-inline-styles-in-react (see the topmost, but not the accepted answer)

Comment: However, why do you need an inline `!important`? An inline style should have a higher priority by default, unless you have `fill: ... !important` in the global CSS or something like that

Comment: @qrsngky yes.. i do have a global CSS with !important so I want to overwrite it

Comment: possible to add the final DOM rendered version of the circle element?

Answer (score 0):

In React, applying !important directly within the inline style object may not work as expected because the !important declaration is specific to CSS and is not directly supported in React's inline styles.

Official source: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881#issuecomment-542656865

However, you can achieve the same effect by using a CSS class with !important

```
.fill-important {
  fill: url('#linear-gradient') !important;
}

<circle className="cls-1 fill-important" cx="84.194" cy="83.49" r="83.48" style={{strokeWidth:'0px'}} />
```

Comment: sorry..  the `fill` property here is the same I use,  it was a typo when I post it..

Comment: In React, applying !important directly within the inline style object may not work as expected. I edited the answer, please take a look.